# ffi library can't be loaded from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl

Tags: python, mysql, windows, anaconda, ffi

I'm trying to open a mysql database on windows 10, with anaconda (python 3.7 64 bit) and the pymysql package.

From windows command prompt, I do the following :

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='tester', passwd='xxxx', port=3306, db='mydb')
```

Username, password and port are correct; the host should be localhost (I get the same error if  I pass 127.0.0.1); but I get the following error, which at the end states that it can't find the ffi package:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 873, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = _auth.caching_sha2_password_auth(self, auth_packet)
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\_auth.py", line 252, in caching_sha2_password_auth
    data = sha2_rsa_encrypt(conn.password, conn.salt, conn.server_public_key)
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\_auth.py", line 132, in sha2_rsa_encrypt
    rsa_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(public_key, default_backend())
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py", line 15, in default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 53, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
  File "C:\programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've seen that conda navigator (nor pip) doesn't see an ffi package from its standard channels.

I have already tried this suggestion (adding the conda-forge channel) :

conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install libffi

but conda takes forever in "solving environment" and doesn't give answers in reasonable time.

What am I supposed to do to install ffi and being able to connect to the db ? Am I the first in the world in calling mysql from python/Anaconda on windows ? I suppose there must be a solution.

Thanks, Marco

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem. Here's what solved it for me:

`1. pip uninstall scrapy
2. conda uninstall scrapy
3. pip install --force --upgrade scrapy
4. scrapy startproject dingding`

It works.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error:

```
File "/root/ncs/bootloader/mcuboot/scripts/imgtool.py", line 22, in <module>
    main.imgtool()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/ncs/bootloader/mcuboot/scripts/imgtool/main.py", line 111, in getpub
    key = load_key(key)
  File "/root/ncs/bootloader/mcuboot/scripts/imgtool/main.py", line 74, in load_key
    key = keys.load(keyfile)
  File "/root/ncs/bootloader/mcuboot/scripts/imgtool/keys/__init__.py", line 52, in load
    backend=default_backend())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 14, in default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 113, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: this module was compiled for Python 3.5
```

#### Solution:

- Search `_cffi_backend.cpython*.so` in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`
- Kill these `_cffi_backend.cpython*.so`
- Search `cffi` directories in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`
- Kill these directories
- `pip3 install --force-reinstall cryptography`

Answer (score 0):

cryptography.hazmat.bindings is fluid, one may need to take a look at sources. I resorted to non-future-proof code like this:

```
try:
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import lib as libopenssl
except ImportError:
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import _openssl
    libopenssl =  _openssl.lib
```